# Conda install R 3.4.0

Tags: r, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install R 3.4.0 through conda but seems like is currently missing in the channel.

```
((Renv)) $ conda install -c r r=3.4.0
```

gives

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - r 3.4.0*
```

Is there any way I can install 3.4.0 through in a conda environment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The latest version of r available through the r channel is 3.3.2. You can install that like this:

```
conda install -c r r=3.3.2
```

You can always look through anaconda.org to look at a complete list of packages from default and community channels.

Comment: thanks. I just found this conda site listing all the r packages : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64/ . Indeed 3.3.2 is the latest.

Comment: Is that possible to install the newest R?

Comment: currently 3.4.3 is the latest available version in conda r channel: [https://anaconda.org/r/r](https://anaconda.org/r/r)

Answer (score 4):

You can now install R 3.4.1 through conda.